# lighttpd mod_rewrite all

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

i need an regex to do the following:

- redirect EVERY request to the index.php
- if there are get parameters in the url i need to access them with $_GET[] (php)

My (not complete) solution is:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
   ".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1&full_request=$0"
)
```

But the error here is that if there's not an "?" in the url i get an "404 not found".

Thanks in advance for help,
dexcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/[^?]*(\?(.*))?$" => "/index.php?$1&full_request=$0"
)
```